# how do I navigate from screen 1 to screen b?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

My navigation tree is like

mainNav

- Nav 1

  - screen a
  - Nav2

    - screen b
    - screen c
- Nav3

  - Nav3.1

    - screen 1

I tried using

```
navigation.navigate('Nav1',{screen:'Nav2',params:{screen:'screen b'}})
```

but it did'nt work and is giving me last visited screen in Nav1

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get to the Nav3 level first and from there navigate to nav1, screen nav2 and finally screen b